# Programmatically set 'Monitor File (upload on External Save)' on specified files in sublime text app

Tags: sublimetext

[image]

Every time I close my sublime text application. I always have to re-click 'Monitor file 'external save' on my css files so when they compile, they get uploaded to server.

Is there any way to add some code to `name.sublime-project` or the `sftp-config.json` file to programmatically always 'Monitor File (upload on External Save)' specified files?

Thanks

Comment: Did you by any chance find any solution ?

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg Nah not yet. Not sure it's possible